# Create a "base" git branch from a previous branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Currently, I have a software which is designed for one specific version (let's call this version version A).

Now, different version are required and I would like to represent this with different GIT branches where changes to a base branch can be merged into the different specialized branches.  The result should look something like the below

```
           |version A-------|------
base-------|----------------|
           |version B-------|-----
```

However, to create this base branch from version A various files have to be deleted. Upon a merge with the base branch, these changes are also applied to the version A branch and therefore this version becomes unusable. I managed to ignore the commits where files are deleted using an interactive rebase, but upon the next merge, these dropped commits are getting applied again. Therefore, I would have to do an interactive rebase every time I merge with the base version.

Is there no good way to permanently ignore these commits for the version A branch which still allows me to merge future commits to the base branch in the version A branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do a:

```
git checkout A
git merge -s ours base
```

Any subsequent merge from base to `A` should not take into account deleted files, because those deletions are supposed to have been merged (except the `-s ours` merge strategy would have ignored them, which was the goal)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I have been looking for.